# Cannot make a secured connection from Celery to Redis

Tags: docker, flask, redis, docker-compose, celery

I'm following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) tutorial, and adjusting the Celery-background related code to my project.

In my case I am operating in a Docker environment, and I have a secured site (i.e. https://localhost).
I adjusted the code for secure connection as follows:

```
key_file = '/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key'
cert_file = '/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt'
ca_file = '/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.ca.crt'

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'rediss://redis:6380/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'rediss://redis:6380/0'

def make_celery(app):
    """Setup celery."""
    celery = Celery(app.import_name,
                    backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    broker_use_ssl = {
                        'ssl_keyfile': key_file,
                        'ssl_certfile': cert_file,
                        'ssl_ca_certs': ca_file,
                        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
                    },
                    redis_backend_use_ssl = {
                        'ssl_keyfile': key_file,
                        'ssl_certfile': cert_file,
                        'ssl_ca_certs': ca_file,
                        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
                    })
```

My docker-compose file look like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - /home/avner/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webServer/web:/home/flask/app/web
      - data2:/home/flask/app/web/project/avner/img
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -t 3600 -b :8000 project:app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /home/avner/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webServer/web:/home/flask/app/web
      - data2:/home/flask/app/web/project/avner/img
    depends_on:
      - web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./postgresql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - data1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "5432"

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: "redis:alpine"
    command: --port 6380
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '6380'
    ports:
     - "6380:6380"
    volumes:
     - /home/avner/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webServer/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

  celery:
    build:
      context: ./web
    command: watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern=*.py --recursive -- celery worker -A project.celery  --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - /home/avner/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webServer/web:/home/flask/app/web
      - /home/avner/avner/constructionOverlay/code/meshlabjs/branches/meshlabjs_avnerV1/webServer/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - data2:/home/flask/app/web/project/avner/img
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  data1:
  data2:
```

The files: key_file, cert_file, and ca_file are generated using a self-CA with the following steps, similar to the steps [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/):

- create a self CA
- sign a certificate to my localhost, outside of Docker
- mount the files to Docker

After doing this change, I don't see connection errors. The containers start ok, and the log file is quite!
**But at run time, when calling a Celery task from my web container I get an error, in my web container.**

From my javascript I have a POST call:

```
let queryUrl = 'http://localhost/api/v1_2/create_zip_file3';
let fetchData = { 
    method: 'POST', 
};
let response = await fetch(queryUrl, fetchData);
```

Here is the code in Flask web container:

```
@sites_api_blueprint.route('/api/v1_2/create_zip_file', methods=['POST'])
def create_zip_file():
    print( 'BEG create_zip_file' )
    task = create_zip_file_task.delay(current_user_id=current_user.id)
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('create_zip_file_taskstatus', task_id=task.id)}


@celery.task(bind=True)
def create_zip_file_task(self, current_user_id):
    print( 'BEG create_zip_file_task' )
    # do some stuff
    # ...

# taskstatus -> create_zip_file_taskstatus
@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def create_zip_file_taskstatus(task_id):
    # return the progress status
    # ...
```

The error in the web container:

```
docker logs -f webserver_web_1
...
BEG create_zip_file
172.20.0.5 - - [14/Feb/2020 05:48:32] "POST /api/v1_2/create_zip_file HTTP/1.0" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 492, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 742, in _connect
    keyfile=self.keyfile)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks
Avner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with secure connection was because the ssl keys were not available to the web container.
I fixed it by changing docker-compose.yml

```
cat docker-compose.yml
...
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - /home/webServer/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
...
```

After doing the change, there are no errors in the log file.
But there still seems to be problems with the connection, and when triggering the task, there is no activity on the celery container.
This is a different problem and I track it separately in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243277/no-response-after-connecting-from-celery-to-redis-via-ssl).