# How to generate certs for secured connection from Celery to Redis

Tags: docker, flask, redis, celery

I'm following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) tutorial, and adjusting the Celery-background related code to my project.

In my case I am operating in a Docker environment, and I have a secured site (i.e. https://localhost) which requires secured ssl communication.

The documentation in [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_use_ssl) shows an example on how to provide cert related files (keyfile, certfile, ca_certs). 
But it is not clear to me how to create these files in the first place.

The tutorial in [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) shows how to create a custom certificate authority, and how to sign a certificate with it.
I followed the steps and created the 3 files:

- keyfile - dev.mergebot.com.crt  - the signed certificate (signed by myCA.pem)
- ca_certs - dev.mergebot.com.key - private key to create a signed cert with "self-trusted CA"
- certfile - myCA.pem - "self-trusted CA" certificate (filename in the tutorial: myCA.pem)

Note that I created these 3 files **completely** unrelated to Celery or Redis or Docker.
They were created in my local machine outside Docker. The files don't have the name of the Redis container and the *Common Name* in the cert was set to "foo"

When I use these files in my webapp, there is no connection from Celery to Redis.
Without ssl I do get a connection, so the overall environment aside from ssl is OK - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243277/no-response-after-connecting-from-celery-to-redis-via-ssl)

**Is there any specific requirements to create the cert related files? (e.g. should the Common Name in the cert have the container name "redis", etc... )**

**Is there a way to test the validity of the certs without the app, e.g. by issuing a command from the container shell?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate the cert related files (keyfile, certfile, ca_certs) using the tutorial in [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/)

I first tested that I can connect from my localhost to the "redis with ssl" docker container.
and I described the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253058/how-to-set-up-a-docker-redis-container-with-ssl)

Then I tested that I can connect from Celery docker container to the "redis with ssl" docker container
and I described the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243277/no-response-after-connecting-from-celery-to-redis-via-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the certificate comman name should match the host name also the issuer of the certificate should be trusted by the client .

In your case since you are using a custom CA and generating the certs , the public cert of the CA should be in the trusted root of the client .

Additionally the certificate should be issued to the hostname in your case it will be localhost . Please do note that if you access the site from a remote machine by either using the fqdn or the Up the browser will flag an alert as invalid.

Also to verify the certificates , you can use the `OpenSSL` Verify option.