# How to set up a Docker redis container with ssl

Tags: docker, redis, celery

I'm following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) tutorial.

In my case I am operating in a Docker environment, and I have a secured site (i.e. https://localhost). which requires secured ssl communication.

I adjusted the *web*, and *celery* containers for secure connection.
But I don't know how to configure the Redis container for secure connection with ssl
Note that when I run without ssl connection in the *web* and *celery* containers, the connection is fine.

**How do I configure and run redis with ssl?**

Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

I followed [this](https://redislabs.com/blog/stunnel-secure-redis-ssl/) tutorial to set redis with ssl and [this](https://github.com/madflojo/redis-tls-dockerfile) tutorial to set redis with ssl via stunnel in Docker container.

I successfully tested the connection from my localhost to the redis docker container, by invoking `redis-cli` from localhost (via stunnel) to the redis docker container, using the following call from the localhost:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6381
127.0.0.1:6381> auth foobared
OK
127.0.0.1:6381>
```

**Related files on the redis server Docker side:**

*docker-compose file* (my webapp includes multiple services, but to for simplification I removed all services except for the redis container):

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    build:
      context: ./redis
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "stunnel /stunnel_take2.conf && /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf"
    expose:
      - '6379'
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /home/avner/avner/certs:/etc/certs
      - /home/avner/avner/redis/conf:/etc/redis
```

*redis container Dockerfile*

```
FROM redis:5-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    stunnel~=5.56 \
    python3~=3.8

COPY stunnel-redis-server.conf /

WORKDIR /

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

redis server redis conf file - *redis/conf/redis.conf*

```
...
requirepass foobared
...
```

redis server stunnel conf file - *redis/stunnel-redis-server.conf*

```
cert = /etc/certs/private.pem
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid

[redis]
accept = 172.19.0.2:6380
connect = 127.0.0.1:6379
```

**Related files on the client side (localhost):**

redis client stunnel conf file - /etc/stunnel/redis-client.conf

```
cert = /etc/cert/private.pem
client = yes
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
[redis]
accept = 127.0.0.1:6381
connect = 172.19.0.2:6380
```

Comment: if you dont want docker-compose but just a container capable of running redis on SSL check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308711/5371505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis doesn't provide SSL by itself, you have to do it yourself. There's an [in-depth post](https://redislabs.com/blog/stunnel-secure-redis-ssl/) about it which you can read and follow. Or, if you want to use a Dockerized solution, you can use ready images like [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/madflojo/redis-tls) or [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/runnable/redis-stunnel/). When it comes to setting up Celery to work with Redis over SSL, just follow the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#redis-backend-settings).

Comment: thanks @Tomas
I followed the links that you suggested and was able to create a redis with ssl Docker container.
I edited my steps above.

Comment: [Redis 6.0 comes with SSL](https://redis.io/topics/encryption). No idea yet though on how to use it in docker. Probably mount your certificate data into the container.

Answer (score 10):

I've created an example repo, for how one might setup a docker container to use the new redis v6+ ssl:

- https://github.com/allen-munsch/docker-redis-ssl-example

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  redis:

services:
  redis:
    image: "example/redis:v6.0.13"
    command: ["/app/docker-redis-entrypoint.sh"]
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
      - ./:/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:6.0.13 as base
COPY ./redis/tls /tls
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

redis-server --tls-port 6379 --port 0 \
    --tls-cert-file /tls/redis.crt \
    --tls-key-file /tls/redis.key \
    --tls-ca-cert-file /tls/ca.crt
```

gen-redi-certs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# COPIED/MODIFIED from the redis server gen-certs util

# Generate some test certificates which are used by the regression test suite:
#
#   tls/ca.{crt,key}          Self signed CA certificate.
#   tls/redis.{crt,key}       A certificate with no key usage/policy restrictions.
#   tls/client.{crt,key}      A certificate restricted for SSL client usage.
#   tls/server.{crt,key}      A certificate restricted for SSL server usage.
#   tls/redis.dh              DH Params file.

generate_cert() {
    local name=$1
    local cn="$2"
    local opts="$3"

    local keyfile=tls/${name}.key
    local certfile=tls/${name}.crt

    [ -f $keyfile ] || openssl genrsa -out $keyfile 2048
    openssl req \
        -new -sha256 \
        -subj "/O=Redis Test/CN=$cn" \
        -key $keyfile | \
        openssl x509 \
            -req -sha256 \
            -CA tls/ca.crt \
            -CAkey tls/ca.key \
            -CAserial tls/ca.txt \
            -CAcreateserial \
            -days 365 \
            $opts \
            -out $certfile
}

mkdir -p tls
[ -f tls/ca.key ] || openssl genrsa -out tls/ca.key 4096
openssl req \
    -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 \
    -key tls/ca.key \
    -days 3650 \
    -subj '/O=Redis Test/CN=Certificate Authority' \
    -out tls/ca.crt

cat > tls/openssl.cnf <<_END_
[ server_cert ]
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
nsCertType = server
[ client_cert ]
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
nsCertType = client
_END_

generate_cert server "Server-only" "-extfile tls/openssl.cnf -extensions server_cert"
generate_cert client "Client-only" "-extfile tls/openssl.cnf -extensions client_cert"
generate_cert redis "Generic-cert"

[ -f tls/redis.dh ] || openssl dhparam -out tls/redis.dh 2048
```

Comment: how can I do this inside a plain Dockerfile without compose

Comment: @PirateApp you can mount the `tls` directory, and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141402/build-and-run-dockerfile-with-one-command I think its the `-v` flag with docker to mount a volume https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/